# Read a Sankey Diagram from a html file

Tags: r, knitr, networkd3, xaringan

I am making slides in the R package Xaringan and I want to present a few Sankey diagrams. I have them in a folder as html files. How can I load the diagrams into my presentation?

Comment: Hi Valtyr, can you make this a minimum reproducible example please? There is not enough information provided to work your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with reading html files into an Rmd file. Start with creating and saving a Sankey Network:

```
# this is from the help section of NetworkD3)
library(networkD3)
# Load energy projection data
URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
              'master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

sn <-sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
             Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
             units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

saveNetwork(sn,"Sankey.html")
```

Then create an Rmd file and do the following recomended by [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) in his answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189740/insert-html-tables-in-knitr-documents-in-r).

````
---
title: "Read Sankey into Rmarkdown file"
author: "user"
output: html_document
---

Read a Sankey diagram into a Rmd file
```{r Sankey, results='asis'}
tmp <- URLencode(paste(readLines(paste(getwd(),"Sankey.html",sep = "/")), collapse="\n"))
cat('<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,', tmp ,'" style="border: solid; seamless:seamless; width: 100%; height: 200px"></iframe>')
````